# Select range from active cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Attempting to get a range one row high of data between Col A and S to be activated regardless of where the Active Cell is in that row. Need to avoid selecting by cell locations as every time function would run will be a different row.
Thanks

```
function getFirstCellInRow() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var rowData = activeCell.offset(0, 18- activeCell.getColumn());
  var range = sheet.getRange(rowData);
range.activate();

 }
```

Comment: @Jozef: [tag:google-docs] is for questions about the Google word processing application. This question is about spreadsheets :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not really need to use offset. All you need is to grab the row number from the active cell `var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow()`. Here is a shorter version of your script that will activate the row from Column A to column S on any row you have active. Change the `19` to change which end column you wish to select

```
function getFirstCellInRow() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 19).activate();    
}
```

you can also do

```
var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 19)
range.activate()
```

If you want to work with that range later